# python (SimPy) generate random numbers that follow the erlang distribution 

Tags: python, random, distribution, simpy

I am using Python (SimPy package mostly, but it is irrelevant to the question I think), modeling some systems and running simulations. For this purpose I need to produce random numbers that follow distributions. I have done alright so far with some distributions like exponential and normal by importing the random (eg from random import *) and using the expovariate or normalvariate methods. However I cannot find any method in random that produce numbers that follow the Erlang distribution. So:

1. Is there some method that I overlooked?
2. Do I have to import some other library?
3. Can I make some workaround? (In think that I can use the Exponential distribution to produce random “Erlang” numbers but I am not sure how. A piece of code might help me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution, which exists as numpy.random.gamma ([reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html#numpy.random.gamma)). Just use an integer value for the k ("shape") argument. See also about scipy.stats.gamma for functions with the PDF, CDF etc.

Comment: Thank you. In random I only find "gammavariate(self, alpha, beta)" is that the one? If yes, how should I set alpha and beta to match an Erlang distribution that need a μ and σ as arguments?

Comment: Yes, you can use that if you don't have numpy. But notice that while alpha=k, beta is 1/theta (that's just another common method of describing the Gamma distribution parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As the previous answer stated, the erlang distribution is a special case of the gamma distribution. As far as I know, you do not, however, need the `numpy` package. Random  numbers from a gamma distribution can be generated in python using `random.gammavariate(alpha, beta)`.

Usage:

```
import random
print random.gammavariate(3,1)
```

Comment: thank you, but please check my comment on Harel's post on how to match an Erlang distribution using Alpha and Beta

Comment: @george &alpha; = &kappa; and &beta; = 1/&theta;

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd like to accept both answers but I can only one and since Harel replied first..